# how to add +1 after two var is true

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, switch-statement

Just wondering is there anyway to add +1 to var store with two var is true?

using switch or if/else which is better way

```
Var store = 0
Var store1 = 0
Var store2 = 0

var buyer = "";
var seller = "";

switch(buyer){
case 1: buyer = buyer1;break;
case 2: buyer = buyer2;break;
}

switch(seller){
case 1:seller = seller1;break;
case 2:seller = seller2;break;
}

if(buyer == buyer1 && seller == seller1){
store1++
}
if(buyer == buyer2 && seller == seller2){
store2++
}
if(buyer == buyer1 && seller == seller2){
store0++
}
```

continue this way to keep my code work or any other way to improve my code with better way?

like `switch(buyer)"case1" switch(seller)"case2"` then `store0++
switch(buyer)"case2" switch(seller)"case2"` then `store2++`

now easier way, please help

Comment: performance wise both if/else and switch gives the same.

Comment: in your switch statement `buyer=""` but in the switch you are check if `buyer == 1` one is a string the other is an int.

Comment: @Hunt - `Var store = 0` --> `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: is this supposed to be in a function? like what @ajon said, you're setting `buyer` and then immediately doing a conditional based on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code by store the value in a map.

### idea

```
store0 = store0 + m[buyer][seller][0]
store1 = store1 + m[buyer][seller][1]
store2 = store2 + m[buyer][seller][2]

m = {
  <value_buyer1>: {
    <value_seller1>: [0, 1, 0],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

### full version

```
var store = 0
var store1 = 0
var store2 = 0

var buyer = "";
var seller = "";

switch(buyer){
  case 1: buyer = buyer1;break;
  case 2: buyer = buyer2;break;
}

switch(seller){
  case 1:seller = seller1;break;
  case 2:seller = seller2;break;
}

m = {};
m[buyer1] = {};
m[buyer1][seller1] = [0, 1, 0];
m[buyer1][seller2] = [1, 0, 0];
m[buyer2] = {};
m[buyer2][seller1] = [0, 0, 0];
m[buyer2][seller2] = [0, 0, 1];

store0 = store0 + m[buyer][seller][0]
store1 = store1 + m[buyer][seller][1]
store2 = store2 + m[buyer][seller][2]
```

Comment: Sorry i not get it how to use the code you advise.
can you please give me more detail?.

Comment: @Hunt add complete example, hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Because your buyer and seller are both numeric enums, you can use the combination of their values as keys to the store.  This doesn't work if you want `buyer1 & seller2` going to a different store than `buyer2 & seller1`, but they go to the same store, consider:

```
var store_count = {};

if (typeof store_count[buyer+seller] === "undefined")
   store_count[buyer+seller] = 0;

store_count[buyer+seller]++;
```

---

A further example of how this is implemented, called, and some internal documentation:

```
var store_count = {};

function updateStoreCount(buyer,seller){
   // initialize
   if (typeof store_count[buyer+seller] === 'undefined')
      store_count[buyer+seller]=0;

   store_count[buyer+seller]++;

   return store_count;
}

// Example Call:
updateStoreCount(1,2);


/* 
   store[2] == buyer1 and seller1
   store[3] == buyer1 and seller2  -and-  buyer2 and seller1
   store[4] == buyer2 and seller2
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the switch is necessary, if buyers and sellers are numerical indexes anyway.

```
var stores = [0,0,0];

function update(buyer, seller){

    if(buyer==1 && seller==2) stores[0]++;
    if(buyer==1 && seller==1) stores[1]++;
    if(buyer==2 && seller==2) stores[2]++;
}
```